# Responsive element height with backgrounds

Tags: css, background, responsive-design, height

I have an example like this:

HTML

```
<section class="section_1"></section>
```

CSS

```
.section_1{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(../img/tmp.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}
```

I want to achive that the height isn't static but it should have max-height: 500px; and than it should scale, depending on screen resolution.

Tnx for help.

Comment: Does the `section` have any parent with absolute `width` value?

Comment: Nop. He is itself parent. I can add child if we need simulate height or smth.

Comment: So, why is it `float`ed? Besides, when the `width` is relative to the width of the viewport and the `height` is limited to an absolute length, talking about aspect ratio doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please provide a simplified online example to demonstrate the issue in action. It would help us to give a more accurate answer.